# a context for "also"

Tags: word-usage

Consider the following conversation

> Ronald: In my free time, I like traveling and photography. How about you?
>
> Kevin: I like watching movies and TV series. I am **also** a big fan of NFL.

I understand "also" indicates that the speaker is giving additional information. In this particular situation, "also" indicates Kevin is adding another hobby.

However, "also" seems to be used more like the following situations.

> A: I am a big fan of NFL.
>
> B: I am **also** a big fan of NFL.

So, should "also" be used in Kevin's introduction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using "also" in Kevin's introduction is a way of indicating that the idea is linked to another. In this context there is already a link between Kevin's two sentences and a listener would expect to hear something to complete the link. If "also" is missing the listener would expect a third statement to follow. An example might be "I like watching movies and TV series, I am a big fan of NFL, and I like mustard on hot dogs."

If Kevin had said "I also like traveling and photography" the "also" would relate back to Ronald's sentence, and emphasise their common interest.

If Kevin had only said "I also like watching movies and TV series" the "also" would have to relate back to Ronald's statement, so it would mean Kevin likes traveling and photography as well as watching movies and TV series.

If the conversation had begun with "I also like ..." there would be nothing for the "also" to relate back to, so this would be a mistake.

Comment: Your last paragraph is wrong. It would not be a mistake. It would be assumed that what Kevin meant is *[I, too, like travelling and photography.] I also like watching movies and TV series.* Just as with your other analyses, it would refer back to the previous statement given by Ronald. It wouldn't emphasize it, but it would add to it.

Comment: Thanks @JasonBassford. I have edited my answer appropriately.